# Factorial Calculator with a basic BigUInt

Tags: beginner, rust

This is my first rust program. I don't mind this being a strict review.

### What I want Reviewed?

- Idiomatic code.
- Performance improvements.
- Clean code!

### Program Requirements:

- Input a unsigned integer and calculate it's factorial.
- If `q` is given as input exit application.

### Implementation

- Use a big unsigned int implementation with `*=`, `clone` and `+=` implementations. I didn't implement all operators as it is not necessary for factorial.
- Formatting: rustfmt
- Lint: clippy - returns false positives regarding `%`, `/` etc used in operator traits, no other issue was reported.

### Manual Testing Code

I've used below python code to verify my application. It works & there are no compilation errors.

```py
from math import factorial

print(factorial(50))
```

output:

```
30414093201713378043612608166064768844377641568960512000000000000
```

### Program Run Output

```
Enter n to calculate n!, enter q to exit
n = 0
0! = 1
n = 1
1! = 1
n = 2
2! = 2
n = 3
3! = 6
n = 50
50! = 30414093201713378043612608166064768844377641568960512000000000000
n = -1
Invalid input: -1
n = a
Invalid input: a
n = q
Program end.
```

### Code (main.rs)

```
use std::cmp;
use std::collections::VecDeque;
use std::fmt;
use std::io;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::ops;

const BASE: u8 = 10;

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct BigUInt {
    numbers: VecDeque<u8>,
}

impl BigUInt {
    fn _carry_mul(&mut self, digit: u8) {
        let mut temp: u8;
        let mut mul: u8;
        let mut carry: u8 = 0;
        // multiply all numbers
        for i in 0..self.numbers.len() {
            temp = carry + (self.numbers[i] * digit);
            if temp >= BASE {
                mul = temp % BASE;
                carry = temp / BASE;
            } else {
                mul = temp;
                carry = 0;
            }
            self.numbers[i] = mul;
        }

        // process remaining carry
        while carry > 0 {
            temp = carry % BASE;
            self.numbers.push_back(temp);
            carry /= BASE;
        }
    }

    fn _carry_add(&mut self, digit: u8) {
        let mut temp: u8;
        let mut mul: u8;
        let mut carry: u8 = 0;
        // add all numbers
        for i in 0..self.numbers.len() {
            temp = carry + (self.numbers[i] + digit);
            if temp >= BASE {
                mul = temp % BASE;
                carry = temp / BASE;
            } else {
                mul = temp;
                carry = 0;
            }
            self.numbers[i] = mul;
        }

        // process remaining carry
        while carry > 0 {
            temp = carry % BASE;
            self.numbers.push_back(temp);
            carry /= BASE;
        }
    }
}

impl fmt::Display for BigUInt {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        for num in self.numbers.iter().rev() {
            write!(f, "{}", num)?;
        }
        write!(f, "")
    }
}

impl ops::AddAssign<BigUInt> for BigUInt {
    fn add_assign(&mut self, rhs: BigUInt) {
        if rhs.numbers.len() == 1 && rhs.numbers[0] == 0 {
            // do nothing when adding a zero
        } else if rhs.numbers.len() == 1 && rhs.numbers[0] < BASE {
            self._carry_add(rhs.numbers[0]);
        } else {
            let l_count = self.numbers.len();
            let r_count = rhs.numbers.len();
            let count = cmp::min(l_count, r_count);
            let mut carry: u8 = 0;
            let mut temp: u8;

            for i in 0..count {
                temp = carry + self.numbers[i] + rhs.numbers[i];
                self.numbers[i] = temp % BASE;
                carry = temp / BASE;
            }

            if count == l_count {
                // smaller lhs
                for i in count..r_count {
                    temp = carry + rhs.numbers[i];
                    self.numbers.push_back(temp % BASE);
                    carry = temp / BASE;
                }
            } else if count == r_count {
                // smaller rhs
                for i in count..l_count {
                    temp = carry + self.numbers[i];
                    self.numbers[i] = temp % BASE;
                    carry = temp / BASE;
                }
            }

            while carry > 0 {
                temp = carry % BASE;
                self.numbers.push_back(temp);
                carry /= BASE;
            }
        }
    }
}

impl ops::MulAssign<BigUInt> for BigUInt {
    fn mul_assign(&mut self, rhs: BigUInt) {
        if rhs.numbers.len() == 1 && rhs.numbers[0] == 0 {
            self.numbers.clear();
            self.numbers.push_back(0);
        } else if rhs.numbers.len() == 1 && rhs.numbers[0] == 1 {
            // nothing to do
        } else {
            let mut level: BigUInt = self.clone();
            self.numbers.clear();
            self.numbers.push_back(0);
            let mut cur: BigUInt;

            // do first multiplication
            for mul in &rhs.numbers {
                cur = level.clone();
                cur._carry_mul(*mul);

                *self += cur;

                level.numbers.push_front(0);
            }
        }
    }
}

fn new_big_u_int(n: u128) -> BigUInt {
    let mut x = BigUInt {
        numbers: VecDeque::new(),
    };
    let mut temp = n;
    let base = u128::from(BASE);
    while temp > 0 {
        x.numbers.push_back((temp % base) as u8);
        temp /= base;
    }
    x
}

fn factorial(n: u128) -> BigUInt {
    let mut current = new_big_u_int(1);
    for i in 2..=n {
        current *= new_big_u_int(i);
    }
    current
}

fn main() {
    let mut input_text;
    println!("Enter n to calculate n!, enter q to exit");
    loop {
        print!("n = ");
        io::stdout().flush().unwrap();

        input_text = String::new();
        io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut input_text)
            .expect("failed to read input");

        let trimmed = input_text.trim();

        if trimmed == "q" {
            println!("Program end.");
            break;
        }

        match trimmed.parse::<u128>() {
            Ok(n) => println!("{}! = {}", n, factorial(n)),
            Err(..) => println!("Invalid input: {}", trimmed),
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't look if your code was correct, I just look the style:

- use iterator instead of index access
- replace `write!(f, "")` by `Ok(())`
- remove most of type `: u8` and let the compiler infer the type
- remove a lot of unnecessary `let mut`, example `let mut temp`
- Add a `DecIter` that deconstruct a number (need `num` to be generic)
- Use `zip_longest()` from `itertools` to improve `add_assign()`
- Need to add every operation `std::ops::Add` and `std::ops::Mul` for example, (that could improve `mul_assign()` and `factorial()`)

```
use std::collections::VecDeque;
use std::fmt;
use std::ops;

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct BigUInt {
    numbers: VecDeque<u8>,
}

impl fmt::Display for BigUInt {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        for num in self.numbers.iter().rev() {
            write!(f, "{}", num)?;
        }
        Ok(())
    }
}

struct DecIter<T> {
    n: T,
    base: T,
}

impl<T> Iterator for DecIter<T>
where
    T: Copy,
    T: num::Zero,
    T: ops::Rem<Output = T>,
    T: ops::Div<Output = T>,
{
    type Item = T;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if !self.n.is_zero() {
            let next = self.n % self.base;
            self.n = self.n / self.base;
            Some(next)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}

trait Dec<T> {
    fn dec(self, base: T) -> DecIter<T>;
}

impl<T> Dec<T> for T {
    fn dec(self, base: T) -> DecIter<T> {
        DecIter { n: self, base }
    }
}

impl BigUInt {
    const BASE: u8 = 10;

    fn carry_mul(&mut self, digit: u8) {
        // multiply all numbers
        let carry = self.numbers.iter_mut().fold(0, |carry, n| {
            let temp = carry + (*n * digit);
            let (carry, next) = if temp >= Self::BASE {
                (temp / Self::BASE, temp % Self::BASE)
            } else {
                (0, temp)
            };
            *n = next;
            carry
        });

        // process remaining carry
        self.numbers.extend(carry.dec(Self::BASE))
    }

    fn carry_add(&mut self, digit: u8) {
        // add all numbers
        let carry = self.numbers.iter_mut().fold(0, |carry, n| {
            let temp = carry + (*n + digit);
            let (carry, next) = if temp >= Self::BASE {
                (temp / Self::BASE, temp % Self::BASE)
            } else {
                (0, temp)
            };
            *n = next;
            carry
        });

        // process remaining carry
        self.numbers.extend(carry.dec(Self::BASE))
    }
}

use itertools::EitherOrBoth::{Both, Left, Right};
use itertools::Itertools;

impl ops::AddAssign<BigUInt> for BigUInt {
    fn add_assign(&mut self, rhs: BigUInt) {
        if rhs.numbers.len() == 1 && rhs.numbers[0] == 0 {
            // do nothing when adding a zero
        } else if rhs.numbers.len() == 1 && rhs.numbers[0] < Self::BASE {
            self.carry_add(rhs.numbers[0]);
        } else {
            self.numbers.resize(rhs.numbers.len(), 0);
            let carry =
                self.numbers
                    .iter_mut()
                    .zip_longest(&rhs.numbers)
                    .fold(0, |carry, i| match i {
                        Both(lhs, rhs) => {
                            let temp = carry + *lhs + rhs;
                            *lhs = temp % Self::BASE;
                            temp / Self::BASE
                        }
                        Left(lhs) => {
                            let temp = carry + *lhs;
                            *lhs = temp % Self::BASE;
                            temp / Self::BASE
                        }
                        Right(_) => unreachable!(),
                    });

            self.numbers.extend(carry.dec(Self::BASE))
        }
    }
}

impl ops::MulAssign<BigUInt> for BigUInt {
    fn mul_assign(&mut self, rhs: BigUInt) {
        if rhs.numbers.len() == 1 && rhs.numbers[0] == 0 {
            self.numbers.clear();
            self.numbers.push_back(0);
        } else if rhs.numbers.len() == 1 && rhs.numbers[0] == 1 {
            // nothing to do
        } else {
            let mut level = self.clone();
            self.numbers.clear();
            self.numbers.push_back(0);

            // do first multiplication
            for mul in &rhs.numbers {
                let mut cur = level.clone();
                cur.carry_mul(*mul);

                *self += cur;

                level.numbers.push_front(0);
            }
        }
    }
}

fn new_big_u_int(n: u128) -> BigUInt {
    BigUInt {
        numbers: n.dec(u128::from(BigUInt::BASE)).map(|x| x as u8).collect(),
    }
}

fn factorial(n: u128) -> BigUInt {
    (2..=n)
        .map(new_big_u_int)
        .fold(new_big_u_int(1), |mut acc, n| {
            acc *= n;
            acc
        })
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(
        "30414093201713378043612608166064768844377641568960512000000000000",
        format!("{}", factorial(50))
    );
}
```